# Bouldering guide for Hampi (India)

Tags: india, climbing

As part of my trip to India I am planning to do some bouldering (climbing on small boulders) in Hampi. Could anyone advise:

1. What is the best climbing guidebook for the area and how can I buy it in the UK
2. How can I rent a crash mat in Hampi? What are the prices, how to arrange it, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bouldering and rock climbing in India is still in initial stages. Hence it will be difficult for one to find any rental shops (probably none) in Hampi. And [Lonely planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/india/karnataka/hampi/activities/rock-climbing/rock-climbing) says it is better to bring a decent bouldering mat and plenty of gear from home. And also Hampi being a UNESCO heritage center, bolting is limited to places.

And with respect to guide book, I found one written by [Rohit Chauhan](http://climbinginindia.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/climbing-guide-book-of-hampi-and-badami.html). I can't comment on the book as I don't have one. As per the book details, author is currently residing in Spain. Hence getting the book shipped to your UK should be easy.

On a similar note, try to plan your visit to Hampi between October/November and January (winter in India). Rock climbing in summer is a task next to impossible due to the heat. It would be better if you are in a group (4-5) instead of just one or two going for rock climbing.

**Update:** A friend replied to my tweet saying, one can in fact rent the equipment in cafes in Hampi. And one of his friend has a guidebook with list of all rocks in Hampi. Will update once I get book information.

**Update 2:** Detals in Gapp's answer :)

Answer (score 9):

I left my copy of the Rohit Chauhan book at the Cafe in Hampi. Just go to Hotel Vijayraghav (the first hotel, as you cross the river from the ruin side to the rock climbing side) and check the desk for books. Feel free to use it and leave it back in the desk for future visitors :)

As for crash mats, you can rent them there. At the same Vijayraghav hotel, you have a kid, a good climber, Jerry and he has some good crash mats. The smaller one would cost about Rs.60 (approx 0.8 pounds) and the bigger one Rs.100. Just pick it up from the kid's tent and return it back in the evening.

Comment: I was thinking about second half of November. Is it going to be fine?

Comment: It will be brilliant during second half of November.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidently, I came across this guidebook yesterday:

http://climbinginindia.blogspot.com/2010/04/climbing-guide-book-of-hampi-and-badami.html

accorording to [UKC](http://www.ukclimbing.com/news/item.php?id=54454)
You can order it by contacting **Rohit**: rohit.climber [AT] gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

There is a new and complete Hampi Guidebook now:
http://geoquest-verlag.de/?q=en/node/481

It lists 1400 boulders and routes. For route climbing bring gear. If you dont want to bring a crashpad you can rent it at the guest houses for little money.

Comment: You should mention that you're the author of the Guidebook

Comment: Looks nice though, shame it was not available when I was there :(

Comment: Got it from Thimma. Thanks for the hard work.